# Как уменьшить масштаб сайта в зависимости от разрешения экрана

Tags: javascript, html, css

Возможно ли уменьшить масштаб сайта в зависимости от разрешения экрана.

Например если ширина экрана меньше 1200 то делать масштаб сайта 90%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этих целей нужно использовать медиа запросы `(Media Queries)`.
Пример:
`@media (max-width: 1200px) {..}` - будет применен если ширина экрана <= 1200px

Answer (score 4):

Использовать media queries + относительные размеры или transform: scale